# electrolytic capacitor

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, board

if i changed a **63v 1000uf** electrolytic capacitor for a **35v 1000uf**  what would happen

its a main smoothing cap on a power regulator board thats running @ 67v dc 8amp and i want to reduce the voltage

it all starts with the toroidal transformer  witch is 220 v ac 6.25 amp that connects to the board
i just wondered if i changed a **63v 1000uf** electrolytic capacitor for a **35v 1000uf**  what would happen

---

[image: power regulator board where it says 50v dc and 28v dv when tested its at 67vdc the rest is as marked]

---

say i change the toroidal transformer to a ac 220volt in and 2x 25v out and change the smoothing cap to a 35v 1000uf  that should work on the above board 
to get near enough to 28volts dc [image]

Comment: forgot to say it has 2x 40volt output

Comment: Wait, you've got a 63 V cap on a 67 V bus?  It may not blow up in the next minute, the next few weeks, or maybe even never, but almost certainly that capacitor won't operate acoording to its spec for long.

Comment: What would happen? Your power regulator will keep providing 67V until the 35V cap explode.

Comment: Not an answer to the question you asked, but if you have 120VAC power available and can find a 240VAC primary on the transformer you can get about half the output voltage, or about 33VDC in your case. Never do the reverse (240VAC on a 120VAC winding) or the transformer will transform itself into a smoking charred hulk, probably liberating a lot of fumes of dubious toxicity.

Comment: It would go bang.  Don't forget to wear earplugs and safety glasses.

Answer (score 8):

What you are trying to do fundamentally won't work.  The capacitor rating doesn't dictate the voltage, only at what voltage it will fail.

What you are suggesting is like cutting some beams under a 30 ton bridge to make it a 10 ton bridge so that 20 ton trucks will stop driving over it.  Reducing the strength of the bridge won't change who drives over it, only the consequences of what happens when they do.

Comment: i am trying to reduce the voltage from 67volts dc to 28volts dc –

Comment: Then you'd better ask for THAT. But at such rates that isn't a project for a beginner. Insteda, buy a suitably rated switching DC/DC converter module.

Answer (score 5):

You can't reduce the voltage on a power supply by substituting a lower voltage capacitor. If the supply is generating 67 volts, and you place a capacitor rated at only 35 volts, the capacitor will definitely fail and there is a good chance it will explode.  Do not do this.

Comment: i am trying to reduce the voltage from 67volts dc to 28volts dc

Comment: i do have a av 220 with 2x 25v (toroidal transformer) would that and changing the smoothing cap do the job

Comment: All you need to do is change the transformer. Assuming no regulator is used, the output voltage will go from (about) 1.4 x 4 (64 volts) to 1.4 x 25 (35 volts). Minus a little bit for the rectifier drop. No need to change the capacitor at all.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain 28v DC without any other circuitry (apart from a bridge rectifier and filter), you really need a 20v AC transformer. And never use a capacitor with a working voltage lower than the supply - they can explode and make a big mess.

Or you could use your 25v toroidal and adjust with a voltage regulator. If you don´t need more than a 1A supply, just use an LM7824 (24V output), or for a higher current, try an LM138/338.

More details here:  [LM138/338 data](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm138.pdf)

Comment: its to power  a radio ham amplifier  28v 8 amp or there about its a shame  i can't post a picture  and you will see what i maen